# Connecting C2 device using Java and Hex

Tags: java, sockets, hex, device, fingerprint

I'm trying to connect a fingerprint device (tc400) C2 device on Linux. The hardware vendor provide me with a DLL file which I can't use on Linux so I tried to use socket programming and communicate with the device using hex code. The problem is the device is not responding at all and the code crashes when I try to get the input stream of the client socket.
This is all of my code:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 public class Client{
Socket requestSocket;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
String message;
Client(){}
void run()
{
    try{
        //1. creating a socket to connect to the server
        requestSocket = new Socket("172.16.16.192", 5010);
        //requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5010);
        System.out.println("Connected to Machine in port 5010");
        //2. get Input and Output streams
        System.out.println("-1");
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
        //out.flush();
        System.out.println("D0");
        sendMessage("A5\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x30\\x00\\x00\\x51\\x10"); // getting the device information
        in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());
        //3: Communicating with the server
        System.out.println("D1");
        do{
            System.out.println("D2");
            try{
                System.out.println("D3");

                sendMessage("A5\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x30\\x00\\x00\\x51\\x10"); // getting the device information
                System.out.println("D5");
                byte msg [] = null;
                System.out.println("D6");
                msg = (byte[])in.readObject();
                System.out.println("D7");
                System.out.println("Machine>" + msg);

                //sendMessage(message);
                //message = (String)in.readObject();
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException classNot){
                System.err.println("data received in unknown format");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException unknownHost){
        System.err.println("You are trying to connect to an unknown host!");
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        //4: Closing connection
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            requestSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
void sendMessage(String msg)
{
    System.out.println("D4");

    try{
        System.out.println("D41");
        out.writeObject(msg.getBytes());
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("client>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Client client = new Client();
    client.run();
}
 }
```

If anyone could help me to communicate with the device I will be grateful.

Comment: Can I ask how you got on with this? I have the C3 device and I can only communicate with it on Windows, be great to have a linux alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing binary data in Strings is IMHO a bad idea. Especially because the used getBytes() method of String returns bytes depending of the system default charset (un Linux mostly UTF-8) which may produce unexpected bytes sequences.

You should better use `byte[]` instead of String. Byte arrays can also be defined this way:

```
new byte{(byte) 0xA5, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 (byte) 0x00 (byte) 0x00 (byte) 0x30 (byte) 0x00 (byte) 0x00 (byte) 0x51 (byte) 0x10}
```

Alternatively you can use [Apache common Codec Hex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decodeHex%28char%5B%5D%29) class for converting hexadecimal strings to byte array.

The second mistake is the usage of `ObjectInputStream` and `readObject()` for reading the redurned data. It is designed for reading Java serialized class data. Use better use `DataInputStream` and this code:

```
byte msg [] = new byte[1024];
System.out.println("D6");
int bytesReturned = in.read(msg, 0, msg.length);
```

Note that the result may be incomplete in case the data is not transfered as one block. If you know the exact response msg size use readFull(msg) instead.

Comment: Really I am lucky to see this question also your answer, please I have the same issue here stackoverflow.com/questions/23990924/… :( could you please help me! I will be grateful! @Robert